# How to better visualizing data while working with MySQL Database?

Tags: php, python, mysql, visualization

To double check if my code does the right thing (python and php querying a huge dMySQL dabase) I do `ssh` to my server and fireup `mysql`. Then I start querying... and querying... and querying... And the querys sometimes are really long.

That is troublesome. :-)

Because I have to double check a lot of times if my code does the right thing, I thought if there is a better approach. There must be one! At least I hope!!

What would you suggest?

### Update:

I am using a Ubuntu Linux machine and the server where MySQL is running on is Ubuntu, too. The Server has Apache and PHP running on it.

Comment: What kind of machine do you want to run this tool on / whats your desktop? Windows? Linux? Mac?  phpMyAdmin is great for running on the server, but requires a web server.

Comment: [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) is worth to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using something like [Querious for the mac](http://www.araelium.com/querious/) or [Mysql Query browser for most platforms](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) and I love it. Check out [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) for a free tool.

Answer (score 0):

To see the changes in the database you have no other than to connect to the db and see the results. Best idea is to use some graphical tool to see the changes in the db. This will help you.

1. [Top 10 mysql graphical tools](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm)